# Поключение 2 принтеров

Tags: принтер

Здравствуйте, есть такая проблема: есть два компа и два принтера, один смотрит в мир, другой по локалке, нужно сделать так, чтобы компа печатали на обеих принтерах (т.е каждый комп мог печатать с тем и с другим принтером). Принтсервер не предлагать, если есть какие-нибудь решения, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Принтеры сетевые (т.е. с Ethernet интерфейсом) или локальные, и должны быть расшарены на компах?

Answer (score 1):

1. Располагаешь оба компьютера в одной подсети.
2. Устанавливаешь оба принтера на локальных компьютерах (если я правильно понял, то 1 принтер : 1 компьютер)
3. Делаешь оба принтера расшаренными: Свойства принтера -> Доступ -> Общий доступ
4. Если модели принтеров отличаются, то устанавливаешь дополнительные драйвера через сервер печати (особенно, если это принтеры HP, то через стандартный установщик редко ставятся).
5. Зайти с 1-ого компьютера (назовем его Alfa, второй - соответственно Beta) на компьютер Beta, введя в строке "Выполнить": //Имя_Компьютера_Beta или //IP.адр.ес.Beta. В открывшемся окне должны быть видны расшаренные сетевые ресурсы, в том числе и принтеры.
6. Нажать на значек принтера правой кнопкой мышки (ПКМ) и выбрать "Подключить". (Если драйвера были установлены, то он сразу появится в подключенных принтерах и с ним можно будет работать)
7. Повторить пункты 5,6 на компьютере Beta. Указав, соответственно //ИмяКомпьютераAlfa или //IP.ад.рес.Alfa

Это действительно для Windows XP\7. В случае невозможности отобразить сетевые ресурсы на Windows 7 проверьте в настройках "Центра управления сетями и общим доступом" -> "Дополнительные параметры общего доступа", а именно должны быть включены: "Сетевое обнаружение", "Общий доступ к файлам и принтерам" (Включить или выключить "Общий доступ с парольной защитой" выставляется по желанию и необходимости).

Проблем с сетевым доступом ХР - ХР не было в моей практике.

Answer (score 0):

Ну зависит от реализации "смотрения", в целом можно воспользоватся протоколом ipp.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, а "наружний"-то комп в локаль смотрит?
Какие системы на обеих машинах?
Протокол ipp будет работать только если оба принтера сетевые и оба компьютера находятся в одной сети...
В общем, подробности в студию!